# hHw to pass a system function to MonetDB through R?

Tags: sql, r, monetdb, r-dbi, monetdblite

Using `MonetDB.R`, I want to run this command but I don't want to open up mclient.  Is there a generic way to do this?

```
create function div_noerror(l double, r double) returns double
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from Hannes, the author of `MonetDB.R` --

You can just create it in your DB. This will fail if it already exists, but you can catch that error.  so

```
dbSendQuery(con, "create function div_noerror(l double, r double) returns double external name calc.div_noerror”) should work.
```

here's a slightly longer usage example:

```
# example of division
dbGetQuery( con , "SELECT 1 / 2 AS a" )

# example of division by zero, which causes an error
dbGetQuery( con , "SELECT 1 / 0 AS a" )

# load the `div_noerror` function through a system call
dbSendQuery( con , "CREATE FUNCTION div_noerror(l DOUBLE, r DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE EXTERNAL NAME calc.div_noerror" ) 

# use the div_noerror function instead of the `/` operator
dbGetQuery( con , "SELECT div_noerror( 1 , 2 ) AS a" )

# division by zero now returns a missing instead of crashing the entire query
dbGetQuery( con , "SELECT div_noerror( 1 , 0 ) AS a" )
```